# Can't get Images to repeat in a grid in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting my images to repeat. I want it to be two columns on desktop, and one column on mobile. Before the image would hang off the screen, but now they wont repeat. Thanks to anyone willing to help.

```
 <div class="gridContainer">
            <img  width="100%" src="img.jpg"   >

            <img width="100%" src="img.jpg" >

            
            <img width="100%" src="img.jpg">
                
            <img width="100%" src="img.jpg" >
    </div>
```

```
.gridContainer
{
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100%);
    
    
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.gridContainer img
{
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: its invalid css what you do. `justify-content` is an attribute for `flexbox` not `css-grid`. As such it doesnt even work with css-grid. Then `repeat(auto-fill, 100%);` is invalid too. The right use of `repeat` is: repeat(number of columns/row, width); 100% would already mean only 1 column which doesnt need to be repeated as it is only 1 element and also already spans the entire width. no need for auto-fill.

Comment: I would solve this with pure CSS: see [background repeat](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) and [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 1):

use media queries to use 1 column for mobile screens and 2 columns for everything else as below:

```css
.gridContainer {
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    .gridContainer {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 481px) {
    .gridContainer {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
}

.gridContainer img {
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer">
  <img width="100%" src="img.jpg">
  <img width="100%" src="img.jpg">
  <img width="100%" src="img.jpg">
  <img width="100%" src="img.jpg">
</div>
```